# Magento 2 - Cron Jobs not indexing

Tags: php, apache, magento, awk, cron

I have searched Stack with no luck, I have come from Magento 1 where you could index from the admin to Magento 2 where you have to run cron jobs.

I have a fresh install on a CentOS 6.6 with Cpanel. Running php 7.

I have put up about 150 products so far, however I have reached a point they are no longer appearing on my site. I believe this is due to my cron jobs aren't running.

The jobs I have tried via the Cpanel are as follows.

========================================================================
**This set of jobs give no errors** 
2016-05-21 15:14:03 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:15:04 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:16:03 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:17:03 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:18:03 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:19:02 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:20:03 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:21:02 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:22:03 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:23:03 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:24:03 Ran jobs by schedule.
2016-05-21 15:25:03 Ran jobs by schedule.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/downupne/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log


*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/downupne/public_html/update/cron.php | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log


*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/downupne/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log
```

=======================================================================
**This set of jobs nothing happens in the log**

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento_cron.log


*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update_cron.log


*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup_cron.log
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Nathan